# How do I localise the strings used by the Azure API Management Developer Portal ?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I can't seem to find a way to edit the localised strings using the provided template editor , does anyone have any pointers on this ?

For example if I wanted to change the text 'search products' to something else for example... Where/How can I edit the template and its data ?

Thank you
Le Roi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ugly way to do this:

Edit the template, remove the

```
<search-control></search-control>
```

And add a custom text to the input placeholder

```
<div>    
    <form action="/Products" class="pull-right" method="get">        
    <input type="hidden" name="startEditTemplate" value="ProductList">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input placeholder="My Custom Search products" id="pattern" type="search" class="form-control" name="pattern"  spellcheck="false">
        <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback ap-ininput-button"></button>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The bad part about this is that you are now responsible for updating this piece of code and template.

Comment: Thank you very much ! - It might be ugly but at least we are able to modify it. Let me try it out and report back - will mark you answer soon as I have confirmation. Cheers!

Comment: Awesome that worked - but please update your code segment , the <search-control> tag should not be there at all , else it will override anything you try and do. So basically delete the tag and add the <form> code.